# Transferring logs using syslog-ng `as is` without timestamp and hostname etc

Tags: apache-kafka, syslog-ng

**Background**

1. Apache server running on a machine and producing logs into `/var/log/httpd/error_log`
2. Using `syslog-ng` to send log to a port `5140`
3. Eventually it will be consumed by `kafka producer` to be send to a topic

**Settings**

```
options {                                                                                                                             
    flush_lines (0);                                                                                                                
    time_reopen (10);                                                                                                               
    log_fifo_size (1000);                                                                                                          
    long_hostnames (off);                                                                                                           
    use_dns (no);                                                                                                                   
    use_fqdn (no);                                                                                                                  
    create_dirs (no);                                                                                                               
    keep_hostname (no);                                                                                                             
};

source s_apache2 {
    file("/var/log/httpd/error_log" flags(no-parse));
}


destination loghost {
    tcp("*.*.*.*" port(5140)); 
}
```

**Problem**

1. `syslog-ng` prepends **timestamp** and **hostname** to the log data which is undesirable

   ```
   <13>Jan 10 11:01:03 hostname [Tue Jan 10 11:01:02 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
   <13>Jan 10 11:01:03 hostname [Tue Jan 10 11:01:02 2017] [notice] Digest: done
   <13>Jan 10 11:01:03 hostname [Tue Jan 10 11:01:02 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.30 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
   ```
2. Desired output (Each log line `as is` from `error_log` file)

   ```
   [Tue Jan 10 11:01:02 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
   [Tue Jan 10 11:01:02 2017] [notice] Digest: done
   [Tue Jan 10 11:01:02 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.30 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
   ```

**Platform**

- CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
- syslog-ng @version:3.2

**PS**
[Syslog-ng to Kafka Integration](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-kafka.html) : Please let me know if anybody has tried this which will render my java Kafka producer redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use the flags(no-parse) option in syslog-ng, then syslog-ng does not try to parse the different fields of the message, but puts everything into the MESSAGE field of the incoming log message, and prepends a syslog header. To remove this header, use a template in your syslog-ng destination:

```
template t_msg_only { template("${MSG}\n"); };
destination loghost {
tcp("*.*.*.*" port(5140) template(t_msg_only) ); 
}
```

To use the Kafka destination of syslog-ng, you need a newer version of syslog-ng (I'd recommend 3.8 or 3.9). [Peter Czanik has written a detailed post about installing new syslog-ng rpm for CentOS](https://www.balabit.com/blog/installing-latest-syslog-ng-on-rhel-and-other-rpm-distributions/).